# Bare minimum set up for PhoneGap/Cordova development on Linux using PhoneGap Build

Tags: linux, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

So I played a little with PhoneGap about 3 years ago. I was writing basic html and javascript and pushing to a github repo. PhoneGap Build would then pull from that repo and build me an APK that I could install to my phone.

Fast forward three years and node has been introduced to make the process a little slicker.

Except I modified the hello world app to include a button to do a barcode scan using:

```
phonegap plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner
```

And then tried to use the barcode scanner by adding a button with the following as an onclick event (added to the pre-existing app object):

```
buttonPressed: function() {
    alert("Clicked");
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function (result) {
          alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
        }, 
        function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
    );
}
```

If I use the phonegap developer app on my android phone I get the first alert, but nothing else. If I use phonegap build to get an APK I get a bunch of failing specs in Jasmine, e.g.

```
cordova.require object should exist BarcodeScanner plugin should exist.

module cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner not found

cordova.require object should exist should contain a scan function.

cordova.require object should exist should contain an encode function.

cordova.require object should exist should contain three DestinationType constants.
```

I haven't added any platforms to my local development because I wasn't really planning on building there. Plus I'm on Linux so I can't add an iOS platform even if I want to.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include `cordova.js` file. You need to `build` your cordova project everytime you do the changes.

Comment: Thanks. So I need to add a platform locally so I can build the project?

Comment: you just run cordova platform add android/ios to add platform